# ¿Cómo obtener el precio tachado con Selenium o Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Bueno estoy tratando de scrapear una página y me pasa que por algún motivo no carga la página entera(creo), y solo me toma algunos elementos con `BeautifulSoup` , traté de solucionarlo con `Selenium`, pero el inconveniente sigue. Mi objetivo es obtener los dos precios de cada elemento.

```
browser.get('https://www.lojasrenner.com.br/c/feminino/blusas-e-camisetas/-/N-1w31qx8Z1i71mb4Z1hwylc0/p2')

#bajo con el scroll para forzar que carguen los productos
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
page = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')
try:
    articulos = [i.find_all(class_='item_product') for i in page.find_all(class_='wrapper cf results-list js-results-list')][0]
except:
    #SIGNIFICA QUE NO SE ENCONTRARON RESULTADOS, PAGINA VACIA
    pass

browser.implicitly_wait(50)

element_price = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('price_product')
# class price
prices = [ene.find_elements_by_class_name('price')[0].text for ene in element_price]
```

Luego note que podía leer el `json` pero solo tiene un precio, dicho conjunto, entonces no me sirve esta solución:

```
for articulo in articulos:
    data = json.loads(articulo['data-product-gtm'])

#Solo tiene el precio comun
print(data['price'])
```

y estas son las formas que intente de obtener el precio:

```
output:
prices
['R$ 29,90 R$ 25,90',
 'R$ 39,90',
 'R$ 39,90 R$ 29,90',
 'R$ 99,90 R$ 79,90',
 'R$ 59,90 R$ 39,90',
 'R$ 49,90 R$ 39,90',
 'R$ 79,90',
 'R$ 89,90 R$ 59,90',
 'R$ 29,90',
 'R$ 69,90',
 'R$ 119,90 R$ 99,90',
 'R$ 39,90',
 'R$ 59,90 R$ 39,90',
 'R$ 89,90 R$ 39,90',
 'R$ 69,90 R$ 29,90',
  ...
 'R$ 99,90',
 'R$ 59,90',
 'R$ 139,90',
 'R$ 79,90']
#como se ve en este ejemplo, no me toma el ultimo precio que es 89.90 (tachado)

#De esta manera saque los precios publicados sin el precio tachado
a = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('best_price')
for b in a:
    print(b.text)

#De esta manera en teoria debería salir, pero me toma solo los primeros
F = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('old_price')
for b in F:
    print(b.text)
#Y el output de este sale cortado asi :

R$ 29,90
R$ 39,90
R$ 99,90
R$ 59,90
R$ 49,90
R$ 89,90
R$ 119,90
R$ 59,90
R$ 89,90
R$ 69,90
```

Bueno espero que se haya entendido el problema, *Solo necesito los dos precios*.

Gracias

Comment: El problema de sacar por separado `best_price` y `old_price`, es que no todos los items tienen `old_price` por lo que luego no sabrías a qué `best_price` corresponde cada `old_price` obtenido. Veo mejor sacar el texto de `price` con lo que te vienen los dos si están, o sólo uno si sólo hay `best_price`, y luego separar esa cadena en los dos precios. En cuanto a por qué no te carga el último, sólo se me ocurre que puede depender de si le ha dado tiempo a cargarlo, pues los `old_price` los obtiene dinámicamente con AJAX. Prueba a esperar un poco más antes de la extracción.

Comment: he notado que moviendo el scroll justo donde se ubica el ultimo producto, o sea `window.scrollTo(0, 5000)` , fue la única manera de poder tomar todos los precios

Comment: Quizás es que la "caja" donde se muestra cada producto sólo "reacciona" ante el evento `onFocus`, es decir, cuando ese elemento está siendo visible, y sólo entonces hacen la llamada AJAX para obtener ese precio. Si haces un scroll demasiado rápido hasta el final de la página, puede que los elementos intermedios no reciban el evento `onFocus` y se queden sin precios. Si esta hipótesis fuese correcta, es posible que te estés perdiendo también precios intermedios aparte del último. Deberías entonces hacer un scroll "a saltitos" para que todos los elementos sean expuestos.

Comment: Efectivamente pasa eso, ahora se me ocurrió, hacer `.move_to_element` , `.perform()` e iterar producto a producto, pero creo que haciendo lo que me dijiste sería más rápido, muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

He creado una lista de precios utilizando [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#):

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Definir direccion
url = "https://www.lojasrenner.com.br/c/feminino/blusas-e-camisetas/-/N-1w31qx8Z1i71mb4Z1hwylc0/p2"

#Acceder a página con la librería urllib
req =Request(url)

#Cargar el html de la pagina
content = urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

# Seleccionar todos los elementos class = '.description_product js-desc'
allprods = soup.select('.description_product.js-desc')

print(len(allprods))

list_precios = []

for product in allprods:
    precio = product.select('.best_price.js-available.js-list-price')[0].string
    list_precios.append(precio.strip())
print(list_precios)
```

El resultado es este:

```
['R$ 25,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 29,90', 'R$ 79,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 79,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 29,90', 'R$ 59,90', 'R$ 69,90', 'R$ 99,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 29,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 49,90', 'R$ 59,90', 'R$ 29,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 49,90', 'R$ 49,90', 'R$ 79,90', 'R$ 69,90', 'R$ 139,90', 'R$ 79,90', 'R$ 59,90', 'R$ 79,90', 'R$ 49,90', 'R$ 59,90', 'R$ 35,90', 'R$ 59,90', 'R$ 99,90', 'R$ 59,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 29,90', 'R$ 29,90', 'R$ 49,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 49,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 39,90', 'R$ 79,90', 'R$ 139,90', 'R$ 79,90']
```

No pretendo resolver todo el problema pero puede servirte de guía. Saludos

Comment: precisamente en eso no necesitaba ayuda, pero gracias de todos modos